# How to add another PHP version in WAMP Server?

Tags: php, wamp

just need a little help here. I have a project that works on the lower version of PHP which is 5.3.0 and if I open my project in the latest version I always got an error. Because of the version. Is there a way that I can include 2 different versions? And just switch to the old version if I need it? Right now I have PHP 5.3.0 in my Wamp and I want to have the latest version too. Can I still keep the old version together with the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download and add any version of PHP they make available. After installation you can switch by:

1. left clicking on the WAMP icon
2. mousing over the "PHP" menu item
3. mousing over the "version" menu item
4. selecting the version of PHP you want to run.

Comment: Is there any way to have two PHP interpreters running at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but not on the same daemon I believe. Unless you set up different file extensions for each.

Comment: @ernie RE: 2 interpreters at the same time in a single Apache. Yes it is possible using Virtual Hosts. Ask the question, see what you get.